# Encrypted SQLite database cannot be attached: "Unable to open the database file"

Tags: apache-flex, sqlite, air

The database can be open()ed using the same encryption key and it works fine. Tried with multiple encrypted databases - all can be opened, but not attached.

This works when encrypted and when not encrypted (bytearray is null):

```
connection.open(file, "create", false, 1024, bytearray);
```

This only works when not encrypted:

```
connection.attach("db" + newnum.toString(), file, new Responder(attachEncryptedSuccess, openEncryptedError), bytearray);
```

Any help is appreciated.

UPDATE:

Just found a strange pattern here:

It seems that if I create an encrypted database, and then create new databases and attach them, everything works fine.

The created files, after unloading, will only be properly opened using the command that they were initially created with. Therefore, the encrypted database that I created before using open() will only open with open() method. All the encrypted databases that were initially created using attach() will only be able to be opened using attach(). It also doesn't matter which database was open()ed first, aka which one is the main database. It can even be not encrypted.

This is something very strange. Is this a bug? Or am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

One gotcha that I ran into awhile ago, and it sounds like it might be impacting you. If you are creating both db's from AIR then this should work fine, however if you have created one with any external tool - generally most tools will default the `PRAGMA ENCODING = UTF8`. AIR, being Adobe, does things a little different than just straight up telling you that they create theirs UTF16-LE.

According to sqlite rules, differing encoding types cannot be attached one way or the other. One way to verify is to use [sqliteman](http://sqliteman.com/) or some other sqlite editor to verify the pragma settings.

For me, I ended up having to start from a seeded db (empty databases -just the header- were over written by AIR) that was to be initialized from a template database. If I allowed AIR to create my starting db, it was set to UTF16 to which I could not attach a UTF8 template.